# Why are my key and values combining?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashmap

I've written code corresponding to the instructions in stars.

```
// 2 points
    static HashMap<String, Integer> Q1(ArrayList<String> inputList){



     **// Return a HashMap containing all the input
 Strings as keys with values equal to the length of each String**

         String result = "";
         for(String ch : inputList){
             result = result + ch;
         }
        String strings = result;
        int number = strings.length();



        HashMap<String, Integer> x = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        x.put(strings,number);



        return x;
```

Here is the output

```
Incorrect on input: [challenge accepted, testing...]
Expected output : {challenge accepted=18, testing...=10}
Your output     : {challenge acceptedtesting...=28}
```

As you can see for some reason my code combines both the string key and in fact adds the values. Is there a way to separate them?

Comment: `for some reason my code combines both the string key` - you wrote code that does exactly that, so why are you surprised? If you want to put each String as a separate key, don't concatenate them, and move the `put` statement inside the loop.

Comment: Your code concatenates all the string in the input to one long string, then pushes it with the length to the map.

Just see that the `x.put(...)` is outside the loop....